# How to Install GoDaddy SSL Certificate in Amazon EC2

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, godaddy-api

I have a Godaddy Domain for example , website.com which points to a amazon ec2 instance. I bought a ssl certificate from Godaddy for website.com . How can I configure ec2 instance to make website.com https?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu for the server instance, follow the following points:

1. Log in to the ec2 instance using ssh or putty
2. Enable ssl module by executing this command: `sudo a2enmod ssl`
3. You may have to restart the apache server through systemctl: `sudo systemctl restart apache2`
4. Make a ssl folder under your html directory and open it:
   `sudo mkdir /var/www/html/my_ssl`
   `cd /var/www/html/my_ssl`
5. Generate csr and key files:

   `sudo openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout my_website.key -out my_website.csr`
6. You'll have to provide these details: Country, State, City, Organization, Unit, FQDN, email, a challenge password, Optioanl company name.
   Note that the FQDN can be website.com or example.website.com
7. Open the csr file through nano or vi and copy its contents: `vi /var/www/html/my_ssl/my_website.csr`
8. Go to your godaddy certificate, click on new certificate, choose the second option that handles csr, and paste the contents into it. If no problem is found, you can continue to the next step.
9. Godaddy will send an email to one of the standard admin emails of the site. If none of them exists, make sure you create it. It will take around half an hour for the certificate to change from pending to valid.
10. Download the key files from godaddy and put them in the apache ssl folder:  `/etc/apache2/ssl/certs`
11. Open the default-ssl.conf file for modification : `sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`
12. Add your website name, and change the default values for ServerAdmin email, ServerAlias, DocumentRoot, set SSLEngine on, and the paths of SSLCertificateFile, SSLCertificateKeyFile, and SSLCertificateChainFile.
13. Finally set the modified file to be the default configuration and restart your apache:

    `sudo a2ensite default-ssl.conf`
    `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Your point 12 is little bit confusion.. Can you add any screen shot or  or explain  where should be add the details

Comment: Point no 10, I am not getting the SSL folder. so I need to create it?