# godaddy ssl certificate on amazon aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have created a certificate on aws and paste that certificate private key to my godaddy ssl certificate rekey option and successfully download that godaddy ssl certificate.

I have created an ec2 instance on aws.
Also created a hosted zone and paste that nameservers on my godaddy domain DNS section and get success on pointing my godaddy domain to my ec2 instance.

But i'm facing a problem in using that godaddy ssl certificate to my aws.

Please give a solution or complete guide related to this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What web server are you using (i.e. Apache, Nginx, etc.)?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @stdunbar i'using Apache web server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61512158/how-to-install-godaddy-ssl-certificate-in-amazon-ec2 has this for Ubuntu.  It might be a bit different if you're using Amazon Linux but the concepts should be the same.

Comment: anyone who worked on aws please connect with me to solve my problem